# Emulator launches behind SDL front-end

Tags: retropie, sdl

I'm trying to add [RetroFE](http://www.retrofe.nl) (using SDL2) to RetroPie as an alternative to EmulationStation.

Unfortunately the emulators launch behind the front-end. I've tried hiding the window, minimizing it, etc., but I get the feeling that since this is running on the framebuffer, these solutions will not help me. I can, of course, destroy the window and renderer, but that displays the TTY for a brief time before launching the emulator, so it's not a very pretty solution.

Any thoughts on how I can solve this in a clean way?